# Why does this code fail to delete the file?

Tags: scala

An example from «Learning concurrent programming in Scala»:

```
package org.learningconcurrency

import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference
import java.util.concurrent.{ConcurrentHashMap, ForkJoinPool, LinkedBlockingQueue}

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

import scala.annotation.tailrec

/**
  * Created by kaiyin on 1/19/16.
  */
import org.learningconcurrency.ch3.Ch3.execute
import scala.collection.convert.decorateAsScala._

object Issue {

  sealed trait State

  class Idle extends State

  class Creating extends State

  class Copying(val n: Int) extends State

  class Deleting extends State

  class Entry(val isDir: Boolean) {
    val state = new AtomicReference[State](new Idle)

  }

  class FileSystem(val root: String) {
    val rootDir = new File(root)
    val files: collection.concurrent.Map[String, Entry] = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Entry]().asScala
    for (f <- FileUtils.iterateFiles(rootDir, null, false).asScala)
      files.put(f.getName, new Entry(false))

    def deleteFile(filename: String): Unit = {
      files.get(filename) match {
        case None =>
          log(s"Path '$filename' does not exist!")
        case Some(entry) if entry.isDir =>
          log(s"Path '$filename' is a directory!")
        case Some(entry) => execute {
          if (prepareForDelete(entry))
            if (FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(filename)))
              files.remove(filename)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @tailrec private def prepareForDelete(entry: Entry): Boolean = {
    val s0 = entry.state.get
    s0 match {
      case i: Idle =>
        if (entry.state.compareAndSet(s0, new Deleting)) true
        else prepareForDelete(entry)
      case c: Creating =>
        log("File is being created, cannot delete")
        false
      case c: Copying =>
        log("File is being created, cannot delete")
        false
      case d: Deleting =>
        false
    }
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fs = new FileSystem("/tmp")
    fs.files.foreach(println _)
    // Thread.sleep(500)
    fs.deleteFile("test")
  }
}
```

It just checks the state of one file and then deletes it, and the code looks like it should work, but after running it, the file I have created by `touch /tmp/test` is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to `FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(filename))` line. According to the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteQuietly(java.io.File)), deleteQuietly does the same as `File.delete()`, but instead of raising exceptions, it just returns `true` if the file was deleted and `false` if it was not.

Adding a debugging log would show that `deleteQuietly` is not working:

```
if (FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(filename))) {
  println("File was deleted!")
  files.remove(filename)      
} else {
  println("File was NOT deleted!")
}
```

It should print `File was NOT deleted`.

So what's wrong? Let's inspect the parameter you passed to `deleteQuietly`:

```
println((new File(filename)).exists()) // returns false
```

It seems that `File` didn't found your file. What is missing?

Since you are only providing the relative path `test`, you need also to provide the parent directory:

```
    case Some(entry) => execute {
      if (prepareForDelete(entry))
        if (FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(rootDir, filename))) 
          files.remove(filename)
    }
```